# How to make different variables refer to same value, while still allowing operations directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is a nice way to make different variables refer to the same value, while still allowing direct operations like e.g. `*` on the value?

Example of desired code is being able to do something like:

```
a = <Reference to integer 2>
b = a
print(a * b)  # Should show 4
<a update (not with assign using =) with reference to integer 3>
print(a * b)  # Should show 9
```

A less desired solution is to use a container for the value, like namespace, list, dict, etc., but this requires reference to the attribute like `.value` below, so is less desired:

```
import types

a = types.SimpleNamespace(value = 2)
b = a
print(a.value * b.value)  # Should show 4
a.value = 3
print(a.value * b.value)  # Should show 9
```

What is a nice way to encapsulate the value, so direct operations is still possible?

Comment: You can't do this without using some sort of container class, since Python ints are immutable.

Comment: What you want is a wrapper class that holds the desired integer as a member, but implements all the methods of the `int` class so that the wrapper instance can be used as if it were an integer in most situations.

Comment: why would you want to do this exactly? the wrapper class would be much more expensive than just another int? there is already the builtin `weakref` class but that is designed for objects that are much more expensive than an int or a string

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It is for use in an optimization machine where values are to be changed randomly in order to optimize some goodness function, but where some values must be identical.  The goodness function is easier to write (and more readable) if variables can be used without considering if it is a plain or linked value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a class which overrides the multiply operation.

```
class Reference:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Reference(self.value * other.value)
```

This will allow you to multiply references by one another directly.  For example, `Reference(3) * Reference(4)` produces `Reference(12)`.

You'll probably want to override `__rmul__` and all the other numerical operations as well.  The abstract classes in [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/numbers.html) may prove useful to ensure you don't forget any.

Comment: `__mul__` return should probably then be `self.value * other`.

Comment: @MortenZilmer: In that case, `other` will need to either be an integer or have an `__rmul__` method.

Comment: Agree, then general solution requires `__rmul__` also, and even all the other operations, but that makes Python do the work of stripping `Reference`.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired behaviour can be simulated with a class, although a bit clunky and inelegant:

```
class reference:
  def __init__(self, num): self.num = num
  def get(self): return self.num
  def set(self, num): self.num = num
  def __mul__(self, other): return self.num * other
  def __div__(self, other): return self.num / other
  def __add__(self, other): return self.num + other
  def __sub__(self, other): return self.num - other
```

With these operators overloaded, the following:

```
a = reference(5)
b = a
print a.get()
print a * 4
```

prints

```
5
20
```

I realise this is quite cumbersome if you want to reference different types, as you would have to overload the operators you need for every type, but AFAIK it's the closest you'll get to simulating pointers.

---

Alternatively, you can include only `get`, `set` and `__init__` in your `reference` class, then add the overloading functions you need later:

```
class reference:
  def __init__(self, num): self.num = num
  def get(self): return self.num
  def set(self, num): self.num = num

a = reference(5)
reference.__mul__ = lambda self, num: self.num * num
print a * 4
```

The above prints `20`

Comment: there are lots and lots of `__dunder__` methods this covers a small subset, but may be plenty :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Manager:
     def __init__(self,data):
         self.__dict__["data"] = data
     def __getattr__(self,attr):
         return getattr(self.data,attr)
     def __setattr__(self,attr,val):
         return setattr(self.data,attr,val)
     def set(self,val):
         self.__dict__["data"] = val


master = Manager(55)
print print master+5
print slave = master
print slave.set(88)
print slave + 10
print master+2

...
master_s = Manager("Test")
print master_s + " String"

...

master_c = Manager(MyCustomClass())
master_c.do_my_method()
```

maybe?

Comment: How is `master + 5` supposed to work when `__add__` is not defined for the `Manager` class ?

Comment: try it :P ... because I define `__getattr__` which looks it up on the data member (int, which definately has `__add__`)  effectively giving this class all the attributes and members of whatever `self.data` is

Comment: Works nicely in Python 2 (after some removal of some "print"), and see that `__getattr__` gets `attr` to `__coerce__`, but looks like that possibility may be been removed in Python 3...

Comment: I'll try it in python3 after lunch

Comment: From [Porting to Python 3 - coerce() and \_\_coerce__](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#coerce-and-coerce) and [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods - Appendix 2: Changes in Python 3](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#appendix2) the coerce feature has been removed from Python 3... pity, since calling a method instead of just throwing an exception would be great in this case, and generally add flexibility.

Comment: thanks for the read(I learned some stuff from SO today :) )... apparently I should brush up on my python3 :P ... It looks like there is no way other than explicitly creating the dunder(double-underscore) methods in the master class in python3 ... I even tried some crazy hackery (I would love to be proved wrong by anyone and have a way for this nonsense to work in py3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list around the object:

```
>>> a = [2]
>>> b = a
>>> print(a[0]*b[0])
4 
>>> a[0]+=1
>>> print(a[0]*b[0])
9
```

Comment: Yes, a list is another kind of container like namespace, just with a different syntax, but it is cumbersome like `a.value`,and I would say less readable and understandable.

Comment: @MortenZilmer what you are trying to achieve is not possible with plain integers, you have to encapsulate the object in something, for example, the aforementioned list.

Answer (score 0):

To use the container classes, but still allow direct operations, you can overload the operators you wish to use for that type.  As an example, define class `SharedInt` and write an overload for the `*` operator that takes two `SharedInt`'s as arguments.

```
__mul__(self, other):
    return self.value * other.value
```